# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$data' (T_VARIABLE) в OpenServer localhost

Tags: php, html

Я начинающий программист и у меня возникла проблема в коде описанная в заголовке. Также я использую Redbean.>это в файле singup.php. **Буду рад тому кто поможет**.

```
    require "db.php";   
    $data = $_POST;
    if( isset($data['do_singup']))
    {
        //здесь регестрируем
        $errors = array();
        if(trim($data['login']) =='')
        {
            $errors[] = 'Введите логин!';
        }
        
        if( trim($data['email']) =='')
        {
            $errors[] = 'Введите email!';
        }
        
        if( $data['password']) =='')
        {
            $errors[] = 'Введите пароль!';
        }
        
        if ( $data['password_2']) != $data['password'])
        {
            $errors[] = 'Пароли не совподают!';
        }
        if ( empty($errors))
        {
            //всё хорошо, регестрируем
        }else
        {
            echo '<div style="color: red;">'.array_shift($errors).'</div><hr>';
        }
    }

?>


<form action="/singup.php" method="POST">

<p>
    <p><strong>Ваш логин</strong></p>
    <input type="text" name="login">
</p>

<p>
    <p><strong>Ваш Email</strong></p>
    <input type="email" name="email">
</p>

<p>
    <p><strong>Ваш пароль</strong></p>
    <input type="password" name="password">
</p>

<p>
    <p><strong>Ваш пароль ещё раз</strong></p>
    <input type="password" name="password_2">
</p>

<p>
    <button type="submit" name="do_singup">Зарегестрироваться</button>
</p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы когда Ctrl+C => Ctrl+V условие, и удаляли trim() - оставили закрывающую скобку

```
if( $data['password']) =='') //тут лишняя скобка после $data['password']
{
  $errors[] = 'Введите пароль!';
}

if ( $data['password_2']) != $data['password'])//после $data['password_2']
{
  $errors[] = 'Пароли не совподают!';
}
```

Comment: Спасибо InDevX, сейчас попробую